# parse non encoded url

Tags: php, redirect

there is an external page, that passes a URL using a param value, in the querystring. to my page.

> eg:  page.php?URL=http://www.domain2.com?foo=bar

i tried saving the param using

```
 $url = $_GET['url']
```

the problem is the reffering page does not send it encoded. and therefore it recognizes anything trailing the "&" as the beginning of a new param.
i need a way to parse the url in a way that anything trailing the second "?" is part or the passed url and not the acctual querystring.

Comment: What does `print_r($_GET);` show?

Comment: it shows the trailing params belonging to the passed url as part of the querystring

Comment: yes. i tried that. and      
it shows the trailing params belonging to the passed url as part of the querystring

Comment: How about parsing $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and stripping out index.php from it?

Comment: sorry. correction. it disregards everything trailing the & in the passed url.  http://1refer.com/test3.php?url=http://www.aaa.com?aaa=bbb&ccc=bb

Comment: index.php is not the problem. the problem is it recognizes anything after the & as the beggining of a new param

Comment: @SammyMiri, if the answers did not resolve your question, please leave a comment explaining this. Otherwise, indicate the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get the full querystring and then take out the 'URL=' part of it

```
$name = http_build_query($_GET);
$name = substr($name, strlen('URL='));
```

Comment: using your idea i did this 'echo $_GET['matches']; 
$name = http_build_query($_GET);
$name = substr($name, strlen('URL='));
$name2 = urldecode($name);' ... but the echo ($name2) shows "&url=" as part of the string

Comment: could you post the echo of $_GET['matches'], http_build_query($_GET) and $name2 please

Answer (score 0):

Antonio's answer is probably best. A less elegant way would also work:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$keys = array_keys($_GET);

$i=1;
foreach($_GET as $value) {
    $url .= '&'.$keys[$i].'='.$value;
    $i++;
}

echo $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

```
// The full request
$request_full = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
// Position of the first "?" inside $request_full
$pos_question_mark = strpos($request_full, '?');
// Position of the query itself
$pos_query = $pos_question_mark + 1;
// Extract the malformed query from $request_full
$request_query = substr($request_full, $pos_query);
// Look for patterns that might corrupt the query
if (preg_match('/([^=]+[=])([^\&]+)([\&]+.+)?/', $request_query, $matches)) {
  // If a match is found...
  if (isset($_GET[$matches[1]])) {
    // ... get rid of the original match...
    unset($_GET[$matches[1]]);
    // ... and replace it with a URL encoded version.
    $_GET[$matches[1]] = urlencode($matches[2]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have hinted in your question, the encoding of the URL you get is not as you want it: a `&` will mark a new argument for the current URL, not the one in the `url` parameter. If the URL were encoded correctly, the `&` would have been escaped as `%26`.

But, OK, given that you know for sure that everything following `url=` is not escaped and should be part of that parameter's value, you could do this:

```
$url = preg_replace("/^.*?([?&]url=(.*?))?$/i", "$2", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

So if for example the current URL is:

```
http://www.myhost.com/page.php?a=1&URL=http://www.domain2.com?foo=bar&test=12
```

Then the returned value is:

```
http://www.domain2.com?foo=bar&test=12
```

See it running on [eval.in](https://eval.in/524173).