# inserting an extra param at the end of the URL

Tags: php

i'm trying to inject an extra param at the end of the query string of a url being passed as a value.
i have tried

```
<?PHP preg_replace('/(http:\/\/www.site.com)/i','$1',$_GET['url']."&EXTRA-PARAM");
```

but sometimes URL does not contain any query string. how can i make it start with ? instead of & if there is no query string presant

Comment: don't. use parse_url to decompose the url into its components. then you can trivially modify the parsed query array however you want.

Comment: it would be simpler for me to use preg_replace. if there is a way of doing it with regex it will not force me to modify the entire code.

Comment: what if your query string already contains your extra parameter then what? ie `?test=1&test2=2&test3=3` and you want to add `&test2=10` ? you need to parse that string like @MarcB said

Comment: that's not a problem. the param im injecting does not exist already in any situation.

Comment: Your regular expression does not actually do anything. It simply replaces the entire pattern with itself. What are you actually looking to achieve by using the regular expression?

Comment: it adds a trailing &EXTRA to the string. i just need ?EXTRA in case there are no other params

Comment: There must be a confusion somewhere. Could you provide a very concrete example of what the value of `$_GET['url']` could be, and what you expect to get as return value (or other effect)? The more specific you are the better we can understand what you need. As it is put now in your question, the *preg_replace* has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The *preg_replace* you have in your question has no effect:

> ```
>  preg_replace('/(http:\/\/www.site.com)/i','$1',$_GET['url']."&EXTRA-PARAM");
> ```

Whatever the last argument is, it will be returned by that *preg_replace* call. Either you don't have a match and nothing is replaced, or you have a match, but then you replace what you found with... what you found. So in both cases you get the same result.

`$1` is a back-reference to `http:\/\/www.site.com`, so actually the quoted statement is equivalent to this:

```
 preg_replace('/http:\/\/www.site.com/i','http:\/\/www.site.com',
              $_GET['url']."&EXTRA-PARAM");
```

Your final value is always:

```
$_GET['url']."&EXTRA-PARAM"
```

So, you could just have used that, and skip the *preg_replace*.

What I answer here is how to better write that part (`$_GET['url']."&EXTRA-PARAM"`), i.e. the question: "*inserting an extra param at the end of the URL*".

This concatenation can lead to missing `?`. Worse, it will not lead to a functional parameter if `$_GET['url']` has a hash (`#`).

Here is a solution for that with [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). It takes into account that a given URL may or may not have:

- a hash (`#`) component;
- a question mark `?`
- some query after the `?`
- some `&` to separate query parts

The function accepts as second argument what needs to be added to the query part of the provided URL, which may be a string (must be URL encoded), or an associative array with items to add to the URL. This array will then be fed to the function [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
function addUrlQuery($url, $qry) {
    if (!is_string($qry)) $qry = http_build_query($qry);
    return preg_replace_callback("/^(.*?)(\?(.*?))?(#.*)?$/",
            function ($matches) use ($qry) {
                return $matches[1] . "?" . 
                    (empty($matches[3]) ? "" : $matches[3] . "&") . 
                    $qry . 
                    (empty($matches[4]) ? "" : $matches[4]);
            }, $url);
}
```

Example use:

```
$url = addUrlQuery($_GET['url'], "EXTRA-PARAM");

echo addUrlQuery("http://myserver.com?x#title", ["EXTRA-PARAM" => 1]);

echo addUrlQuery("http://myserver.com/" . $relative_url, "EXTRA-PARAM");
```

You can see the function run on several test cases on [eval.in](https://eval.in/private/9dce06f0f19049).

### The problem with $_GET['url']

If you have a URL passed as a query argument to the current URL, like this:

```
http://myserver.com/index.php?url=http://test.com/index.php?a=1
```

Then you must realise this is not a good URL. Some characters need to be escaped. Certainly the ampersand (`&`) needs to be escaped. If you have this:

```
http://myserver.com/index.php?url=http://test.com/index.php?a=1&b=2
```

Ask yourself: is `b` a query parameter of the current URL, or of the URL passed as `url` argument?

The answer: it is a query parameter of the current URL. You would access it with `$_GET['b']`. And the value of `$_GET['url']` is now just:

```
http://test.com/index.php?a=1
```

So... you need to escape `&` when you want `b` to be a query argument of the `url` parameter, and not of the current query:

```
http://myserver.com/index.php?url=http://test.com/index.php?a=1%26b=2
```

Note the `%26`: it is the code for `&`. Now if you look at `$_GET['url']` you will get:

```
http://test.com/index.php?a=1&b=2
```

### What if URL is provided without proper encoding?

In this case, you have to make assumptions. If you know for sure that the `url` parameter is the ***only*** parameter you will get on the current URL, then you can conclude that any other you get, really belong to the URL that is passed via that `url` parameter.

You would then take all the parameters from `$_GET`, except `url`, and add them (with the function above) to the value of `$_GET['url']`.

Comment: hi. thanks for sharing. but i dont always use this in the current querystring. i sometimes use it on urls saved in the session. <?PHP preg_replace('/(http:\/\/www.site.com)/i','$1',$sesssion_variable."&EXTRA-PARAM");

Comment: i have edited the question. im acctually passing url's as a value in the querystring. the domain is dyanamic.

Comment: My answer is suitable for any URL and query. You can use it on URLs saved in the session, or on URLs passed via the querystring. The domain can be dynamic. There is nothing in my suggested code that assumes the domain is fixed.

Comment: hi trincot. thanks for your post. i tried it. your solution will only work if there is no second param in the original querystring. secondly. the http_build_query prevents loading the page if the $URL contains a filename in the string which is not a php file.

Comment: correction. its not working  if the $URL contains a non php filename in the string.  regardless of http_build_query

Comment: also, what i meant regarding dynamic was, the domain is dynamic and i only want to specify an additional param to add if a specific domain exists in the string. so every domain will have a specific param added to it.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing but (1) the solution works when original URL already has 2 arguments (see [eval.in](https://eval.in/private/9dce06f0f19049); (2) `http_build_query` does not prevent anything. (3) Of course if you build an URL that points to a non-existing page, then that URL will go ... to a non-existing page. What did you expect? (4) I don't understand what you are saying about the domain. Please provide clear examples in your question.

Comment: I already asked 11 hours ago in the comments section of your question to provide clear examples, because the only code you have put in your question is completely idle: it does not do anything. So there is nothing we can understand from it. Please edit your question and add example input and output.

Comment: this is what i tired with your code.  '$url = addUrlQuery($_GET['url'], "EXTRA-PARAM");
echo $url;'

Comment: when implementing exactly the function addurlquery you posted above. and doing this..  **$url = addUrlQuery($_GET['url'], "EXTRA-PARAM");
echo $url;** it works fine when the string is file.php?foo=bar but not with file.php?foo=bar&hello=world. it leaves our the hello=world. also , file.html?foo=bar will not load at all. will get an apache handler error.  see here http://1refer.com/test5.php?url=http://www.test.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104324/discussion-between-sammy-miri-and-trincot).

Comment: Your problem with missing the second argument has nothing to do with my code, but with `$_GET['url']` and how you encode the value of that `url` parameter on the URL. Check what the value is of `$_GET['url']`  before doing anything else and you will see the second argument is not there. Try to understand that the `&` has to be URL encoded to make it part of the `url` parameter.

Comment: i understand. so how would i go about solving this problem if im dealing with non url encoded urls in the url param? an external page is passing the param non encoded. so i have to find a solution on my end

Comment: The external site is at fault. You need to get the second, third, ...etc argument via `$_GET`.

Comment: I have added info about that in my answer. But we are really deviating a lot from the original question. So I would now suggest that if you have more questions about that, that you ask this as a new question.

Comment: yes. i posted a question about that a few days ago  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493723/parse-non-encoded-url  if you have any suggestions on that it would help

Comment: OK, I will have a look there. I hope the info I provided here has given the answers you needed to the original question *inserting an extra param at the end of the URL*

Comment: I notice that you don't accept any answers to most of your questions, nor do I see any upvotes. Why is that? I think you should consider upvoting good answers and choose an answer to accept (in each of your questions). That is how this site keeps running, and at the same time you reward the people that made an effort and spent time on your question. What do you think? :-)